# how to select dynamic data-attribute element in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, custom-data-attribute

I have many elements like

```
<input  tag="data-initial-222" value="" type="checkbox">

<input   tag="data-initial-111" value="" type="checkbox">
```

How can I select all the elements who have this tag "data-initial-*"

Another Question is :

How to select

```
 <input data-initial="111" type="checkbox">
```

or

```
 <input data-initial="222" type="checkbox">
```

using data-initial attribute.

Comment: I'm not aware of `tag` attribute. Doesn't seem to be a valid one [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). Why not use [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) instead?

Comment: yes, data-* tag is more common. I had to use tag="data-initial-222" for some requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log($("input[data-initial]").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  tag="data-initial-222" value="" type="checkbox">

<input   data-initial="111" value="" type="checkbox">

<input  data-initial="222" value="" type="checkbox">

<input   data-initial="333" value="" type="checkbox">
```

1. Use [starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

2. [Attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

   > Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

Comment: how to select if I have <input data-initial="326" type="checkbox"> from "data-initial" thing

Comment: you mean select starting with 326? `$("[data-initial^=326]")` is this what you mean?

Comment: I mean, all the input types with data-initial tag. Plz

Comment: change your selector to `$("input[tag^=data-initial-").length)` this will select all input with tag tag starting `data-initial-`

Comment: no, this is not working, I have now different tagging type. Its data-initial ="111" or data-initial="222"

Comment: just change the tag with what ever tag you are using `$("input[data-initial^=111").length)`

Comment: it will select only data-initial ="111", I want to select all the inputs with data-initial tag

Comment: I see dont put a specific value use `[attribute]` check update

Comment: I checked using $("[data-initial]"), not found, html is <input id="initialCheckbox" ="304"="" value="" type="checkbox">

Comment: you html is not valid i think it should be like this `<input id="initialCheckbox" data-initial="304" value="" type="checkbox">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148399/discussion-between-rajdeep-and-guradio).

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "input[tag*='data-initial']" )
```